# Interesting task with graphs, proving(tournament)?

Tags: graph-theory

We have a tournament with n players, each player plays with everyone else exactly once. Prove that if there is only one pseudo winner (pseudo winner means that he beat everyone, or if he lost to someone, then he beat someone who beat the one who he lost to), then he is the absolute winner too.

I thought that this could be solved with graphs: We have K(n) a directed graph (all edges are drawn), somehow I need to prove that if there is only one pseudo winner, then there is only one vertex from where I can reach all other vertices with a maximally 2-long route. If only one vertex satisfying the above conditions actually exists, then this player beat everyone else.

I tried something indirect and can't really end it. Any ideas?